# Selenium - Store iframe:src

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a webpage which contains an iframe such as this

```
<iframe src="iframe_src" style="border: none" scrolling="no" id="id_frame" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="1850">...</iframe>
```

I'm trying to [storeText](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#selenium-commands-selenese) the iframe src attribute, but executing the following command won't do the trick:

```
storeText //iframe[@id='id_frame']//@src frame_src
```

I expect frame_src to be equal to "iframe_src"

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: can you clarify:  What are you trying to do?  #1) Store the `src` attribute of the iframe or #2) Store the HTML source of the iframe?

Comment: src attribute, edited the question for clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect frame_src to be equal to "iframe_src"

First off, `storeText` will store the innerHTML of your target.  What *you* want, is the `storeAttribute` command, however we can simplify it using the `verifyAttribute` command.

```
Command         | Target                         | Value
============================================================
verifyAttribute | //iframe[@id='id_frame']@src | frame_src
```